# Can we use correlated sub-query in the group clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table t2 with field Col & a,b,c,d,e as records. I'm trying to get an output like:

```
r1      0   1
1       b   a
2       d   c
4       e
```

---

when i use the below query i get an error: Syntax error in the expresion (((Select Count(b.Col)+1 from t2 as b where a.col>b.col)+1)\2

```
Transform
first(col) as col1
Select  ((Select Count(b.Col)+1 from t2 as b where a.col>b.col)+1)\2 as r1
From t2 as a
Group  by (((Select Count(b.Col)+1 from t2 as b where a.col>b.col)+1)\2)
Pivot
(Select Count(b.Col)+1 from t2 as b where a.col>b.col) MOD 2
```

Comment: What error do you get what you try this?

Comment: error: Syntax error in the expresion (((Select Count(b.Col)+1 from t2 as b where a.col>b.col)+1)\2

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  Just use a subquery:

```
select r1
from (select a.*,
             (Select Count(b.Col)+1 from t2 as b where a.col>b.col)+1)\2 as r1
      from t2 as a
     ) as a1
group by r1;
```

Or, because you are only selecting distinct values, use `select distinct` rather than `group by` in the original query.

Comment: Gives error. ERR: Syntax error in FROM clause. Also you used table alias 'a' 2 times. Can we do that?

Comment: @KT11 . . . It can be done in most databases.  I was not aware of a restriction in MS Access, but you can change the alias.